# Adding dots and a line with second axis to a barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am looking at stranding data in 12 subareas. I have a barplot with the total number of strandings per subarea and I would like to add dots and a line to the plot unisg the stranding rate per kilometre (kmrate) in each 75 km long subarea.

```
> dfo_sba2_noNA
  Subarea  Quantity kmrate
  <fct>      <int>  <dbl>
1   1         96     1.28  
2   2         431    5.75  
3   3         118    1.57  
4   4         469    6.25  
5   5          1     0.0133
6   6          20    0.267 
7   7         313    4.17  
8   8         252    3.36  
9   9          14    0.187 
10  10        118    1.57  
11  11          7    0.0933
12  12         21    0.28
```

With the following code I get the following graph, but the dots and line are not right.

[image]

```
p_sba2 <- ggplot(dfo_sba2_noNA, aes(x=Subarea, y=Quantity)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge") +
  labs(x = "Subarea", y = "Number of observations") +
  geom_point(aes(kmrate, color = "red", group = Subarea)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=as.numeric(Subarea), y=kmrate),stat="identity",color="red")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1600, 200),sec.axis=sec_axis(~./75),
                     name="Stranding rate (per km)")+
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "white"),
    legend.background = element_rect(),
    legend.text = element_text(size=10),
    legend.title = element_text(size=10),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour="black", fill="NA"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    axis.title = element_text(size=10),
    axis.text = element_text(size=10)
  )
p_sba2
```

How can I add a second axis with a better scale? And how do I add the dots and lines on top of the barplot?
I'd like my plot to look something like this, with a stranding rater per bar:

[image]

I know my question is similar to others on this platform, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: Should your `geom_point()` layer have the following aesthetic: `aes(x=Subarea, y=kmrate)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is quite often the case when dealing with secondary axes in `ggplot2` you missed to scale your data. In my code below I use `scales::rescale` to first scale your `kmrate` variable and applying the inverse "transformation" inside `sec_axis`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

to <- c(0, max(dfo_sba2_noNA$Quantity) / 2) # Scale to 50% of max column height
from <- c(0, max(dfo_sba2_noNA$kmrate))

dfo_sba2_noNA$kmrate <- scales::rescale(dfo_sba2_noNA$kmrate, from = from, to = to)

ggplot(dfo_sba2_noNA, aes(x = Subarea, y = Quantity)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_point(aes(y = kmrate), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(x = Subarea, y = kmrate), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 1600, 200),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ scales::rescale(.x, to = from, from = to),
      name = "Stranding rate (per km)"
    )
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "white"),
    legend.background = element_rect(),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "NA"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 10)
  ) +
  labs(x = "Subarea", y = "Number of observations")
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dfo_sba2_noNA <- structure(list(Subarea = 1:12, Quantity = c(
  96L, 431L, 118L,
  469L, 1L, 20L, 313L, 252L, 14L, 118L, 7L, 21L
), kmrate = c(
  1.28,
  5.75, 1.57, 6.25, 0.0133, 0.267, 4.17, 3.36, 0.187, 1.57, 0.0933,
  0.28
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1", "2", "3", "4",
  "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"
))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great. However, the geom_line() does not work on my graph and I get the following message: `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation. ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: This is a famous warning and a ggplot2 classic. You probably mapped `factor(Subarea)` on `x`? As a general rule, when the variable mapped on x is a factor or character (ie non-numeric) you have to set the `group` aes. Try with `geom_line(aes(..., group = 1), color = "red")` which means to treat all obs. as one group which for simplicity we name `1`.

Comment: Yes, that works. I used `geom_line(aes(x=Subarea, y=kmrate, group = 1), color = "red")` and it did what I wanted it to do. Thank you so much!